# Sencha: Google document crashes in IFRAME in iPhone/iPad

Tags: iframe, google-docs, sencha-touch-2

I created one Sencha Touch 2.0 application which requires opening documents with google viewer inside an IFRAME. The files open fine in Desktop browser as well as in Blackberry. But it forces the browser crash in iOS. Here is the embedded src Iframe I am using inside a sencha panel:

```
<iframe 
src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://betagalaxy.classlink.net/Files/Chemistry%20-%20Carbon%20Rings%20v1.ppt&embedded=true" />
</iframe>
```

Did anyone got the same error with Sencha Touch? Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

try to use embed instead Iframe, this is my workaround, so far

```
<embed src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://betagalaxy.classlink.net/Files/Chemistry%20-%20Carbon%20Rings%20v1.ppt&embedded=true" ></embed>
```

Comment: Yup. Thumbs up! For me as well!